# Why won't my scene change in swift sprite kit?

Tags: swift, uiview, sprite-kit

I'm trying to change scenes whenever a `UISegmentedControl` changes index, and my function is running, but the scene isn't changing. All of my scenes inherit the class that this function is located in and I'm wondering if that is the problem, and how would i solve it

this is my code:

```
func valueChanged(){
    run(tapSound)
    let sceneto = scenes[segment.selectedSegmentIndex]
    let trans = SKTransition.fade(with: .white, duration: 1.5)
    if self == sceneto as! SKScene{
        print("na")
        return
    }

    view?.presentScene(sceneto as! SKScene, transition: trans)

}
```

the function is running everytime the controller is clicked, and the scene even changes the first time its run but not after the first time. it just won't change scenes after the 1st time it is run, and it itsnt printing "na" so I'm wondering what the issue is

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's failing because the SKScene of `self` is not equal to `sceneto` at all. If it's not printing "na", than the if statement is failing. Also, you might want to print "sceneto" to see what it equals to.

Comment: that part is only supposed to work if the scene is the same scene its trying to transition to, that part hasn't even gotten called, and the scene still won't transition

Comment: it only transitions once then stops working

Comment: What is the array of scenes? What type?

Comment: the scenes are all of the same type class that this functions is located in because they all inherit this class

Comment: This function should not be in your scene, it should be where you are handling your segmented view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't print 'na', then that must mean that `self !== sceneto as! SKScene`. This would crash if `sceneto` was not an `SKScene` (becasue you use `as!` and not `as?`).

If the `view?.presentScene(sceneto as! SKScene, transition: trans)` does nothing, (no crash, not a transition to the wrong scene but nothing), then that implies that the `view?` is actually `nil`.

From SKScene class reference (https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1519726-view)

> To present a scene, you call the presentScene(*:) method or
>   presentScene(*:transition:) method on the SKView class. If the scene
>   is not currently presented, this property holds nil.

Can you add print("(view)") before the `presentScene`?

Comment: so say the scene is nil how would i make it added to the view so i could transition to it?

Comment: Chris - have you confirmed if the `view` is nil or not?

Comment: yes, the view is becoming nil after the first scene transition. How exactly would i fix that? I'm confused by your answer

Comment: Then I think you need to follow the thread of Apple's documentation, and assume that the scene in which your code is running is not presented. Now, it works the first time, so the code is then in a presented scene, but then it doesn't work again. This is just a guess, but is your segmented control calling a function in a specific scene, which is no longer the presented scene after the first transition to another scene? I think we need to see more of your code to pin down the exact problem.

Comment: the segment calls a function from a class which every scene inherits, so each scene has this function in it essentially

Comment: @ChrisHutchison Is the segmented control is wired up to a view controller via an @IBOutlet? That will have to call your `valueChanged` function in an instance of your class (you're not calling it as a class method) so how is that call handled? It would be very useful to see the code for the view controller.